# Is SSI still relevant?

Tags: server-side-includes

On my work i can see old sites using SSI to include huge parts of code and do some conditional work. I'm just curious is SSI still developing? If not, what modern simple server-side scripting languages exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SSI still have it's niche. It's fast & simple and widely supported.
Maybe no active development of SSI itself as it's perfect for ages.

Answer (score 4):

SSI has (and always had) a very limited feature set that was never meant to compete with real scripting languages. As such, the technology is alive and well. There isn't much to develop...

As for what server side scripting languages exist: I assume you mean built-in languages in the web server? I'm not aware of anything beyond SSI here (and, if you want to count it, the regex-based URL manipulation possibilities offered by Apache's `mod_rewrite`). That's the domain of "real" languages and development platforms.